# div with more than four corners

Tags: css, html

Is it possible to make divs with for example five or six corners?

I need this to make clickable zones on a map. If there is another way to achieve this I would be delighted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. [A block in HTML is rectangular](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-box/).

And even if you change its look using (expensive) [css based tricks](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/), the clickable zone will keep rectangular.

But there are several solutions for clickable zones :

- simple computations with javascript from the event coordinates on click
- the old [image-map format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map)

If you want to do it in javascript without image maps, you may be interested by ready [algorithms to decide if a point is inside a polygon](http://jsfromhell.com/math/is-point-in-poly).

Answer (score 1):

If the map is an image, use a polygon imagemap.  There are several web apps that make it easy to create these (just Google "[imagemap generator](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&sugexp=les;cpsugrpq1&gs_nf=1&tok=mk6h8MHU4AmcE6mUeWuPpg&cp=9&gs_id=5&xhr=t&q=imagemap%20generator&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=imagemap%20&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=f8988a7f1ebacbd3&ion=1&biw=1145&bih=682)").

If you're using a mapping API like Google, they'll have documentation on creating clickable targets within the map (for example: [Google Maps Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays)).